# Skew-symmetric, Time Dependent, Linear Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let

$I \subset \Bbb R \tag 1$

be an open interval, not necessarily bounded, and let $A(t)$ be a continuous matrix function of $t \in I$, taking values in
$M(n, \Bbb R)$; that is

$A(t) \in C^0(I, M(n,, \Bbb R)); \tag 2$

suppose further that $A(t)$ is skew-symmetric for every $t$:

$A^T(t) = -A(t), \tag 3$

and consider the ordinary time-varying linear system

$\dot{\vec x}(t) = A(t) \vec x(t), \tag 4$

where

$\vec x(t) \in C^1(I, \Bbb R^n). \tag 5$

It is well-known, and easy to see, that when $A$ is a constant matrix the solutions to (4) are given by

$\vec x(t) = e^{A(t - t_0)} \vec x(t_0), \tag 6$

where the matrix exponential is orthogonal; indeed we have

$(e^{A(t - t_0)})^T e^{A(t - t_0)} = e^{A^T(t - t_0)} e^{A(t - t_0)} = e^{-A(t - t_0)}e^{A(t - t_0)} = I. \tag 7$

The fact that $e^{A(t - t_0)}$ is orthogonal leads to

$\langle \vec x(t), \vec y(t) \rangle = \langle e^{A(t - t_0)} \vec x(t_0), e^{A(t - t_0)} \vec y(t_0) \rangle = \langle \vec x(t_0), \vec y(t_0) \rangle; \tag 8$

that is, the evolution of vectors according to (4) preserves inner products.

We recall that $e^{A(t - t_0)}$ is a fundamental matrix solution of (4), and we observe that it takes the value $I$ at $t = t_0$:

$e^{A(t_0 - t_0)} = e^{A(0)} = I. \tag 9$

The purpose here is to investigate extending this observation to the case in which $A(t)$ is not a constant matrix.

***The Question*** is then:  given a system of the form (4), with $A(t)$ as in (3), show that a fundamental solution matrix $X(t, t_0)$ of the system (4) with

$X(t_0, t_0) = I \tag{10}$

is orthogonal.  Conversely, show that a system (4) with orthogonal fundamental matrix satisfies (3).

Comment: @J. W. Tanner: thanks for the edit.  Small things like extra "."'s are easy to miss!  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your good humor about that!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  but of course, my friend.  Cheers!

Comment: @CosmasZachos:  thanks for pointing that out.  I haven't yet convinced myself that $\Omega$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: @CosmasZachos:  so if you could explain why $\Omega$ is orthogonal it would really help me out!

Comment: @CosmasZachos:  in any event the Magnus expansion bears more careful scrutiny in the context of my question. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iterative solution of the celebrated [Magnus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion#Magnus_approach_and_its_interpretation)
for your equation
$$\dot{\vec x}(t) = A(t) \vec x(t), \tag 4$$
uses the Ansatz
$$
\vec x(t) =  e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}  ~ \vec x(t_0)  
$$
[so that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map)
$$
A(t)= e^{-\Omega}\frac{d}{dt}e^{\Omega(t)} =  \frac{1 - e^{-\mathrm{ad}_{\Omega}}}{\mathrm{ad}_{\Omega}}\frac{d\Omega}{dt}~~,  
$$
where  ${\mathrm{ad}_{\Omega}} B \equiv  [\Omega, B] $,
$$
A= \dot \Omega - [\Omega, \dot \Omega]/2! + [\Omega,[\Omega,\dot \Omega]]/3! ~ - ~ ...
$$

From (3), however, it follows that $\Omega$ is antisymmetric as well,
$$
A^T=-A=\frac{d}{dt}e^{\Omega^T}   ~e^{-\Omega^T}=- e^{\Omega^T} \frac{d}{dt}e^{-\Omega^T}  =  - e^{-\Omega} \frac{d}{dt}e^{\Omega} .
$$

You may reassure yourself that, indeed, the nested integrals of commutators involved in the solution of $\Omega$ in terms of *A*  yield antisymmetric results for each term of the iteration.

Comment: Very well done, ***+1, endorsed!*** I must pay more attention to this.  Thanks so much.  Cheers!

Comment: patience my friend..  I usually wait a few days to "accept" an answer to see what might roll it.  But thanks for a stimulating contribution.

Comment: I was at "Throop" from '68-'72 and then from '80-'84.  When were you there?

Comment: You will notice I accepted your answer.  Nice work!  Cheers!

Comment: The numbering system for your equations mystifies me.

Comment: Thanks, me too. Better now...

Answer (score 2):

Let $X(t, t_0)$ be a fundamental solution matrix for the system

$\dot{\vec x}(t) = A(t) \vec x(t), \tag 1$

with

$A^T(t) = -A(t); \tag 2$

then $X(t, t_0)$ is a square matrix function of $t$ and we set

$n = \text{size} \; X(t, t_0) = \text{size} \; A(t); \tag 3$

the columns of $X(t, t_0)$ are $n \times 1$ matrices--"column vectors"--$\vec x(t)$ each of which satisfies (1); from this it easily follows that

$\dot X(t, t_0) = A(t) X(t, t_0), \tag 4$

since $A(t)$ acts on $X(t, t_0)$ column-by-column.  We may transpose this equation and obtain

$\dot {X^T}(t, t_0) = X^T(t, t_0)A^T(t); \tag 5$

we next consider $X^T(t, t_0) X(t, t_0)$; we have

$\dfrac{d}{dt}(X^T(t, t_0) X(t, t_0)) = (X^T(t, t_0) X(t, t_0))'$
$= \dot {X^T}(t, t_0) X(t, t_0) + X^T(t, t_0) \dot X(t, t_0)$
$= X^T(t, t_0)A^T(t) X(t, t_0) + X^T(t, t_0)A(t)X(t, t_0) = X^T(t, t_0)(A^T(t) + A(t))X(t, t_0); \tag 6$

it is thus seen that in the event that (2) binds, and so

$A^T(t) + A(t) = 0, \tag 7$

that (6) implies

$\dfrac{d}{dt}(X^T(t, t_0) X(t, t_0)) = X^T(t, t_0)(A^T(t) + A(t))X(t, t_0)$
$= X^T(t, t_0)(0)X(t, t_0) = 0; \tag 8$

we infer from this that $X^T(t, t_0)X(t, t_0)$ is in fact a constant matrix:

$X^T(t, t_0)X(t, t_0) = X^T(t_0, t_0)X(t_0, t_0), \; \forall t \in I; \tag 9$

now suppose

$X(t_0, t_0) = I, \tag{10}$

the columns of which correspond to the $n$ vectors vectors of size $n$:

$\vec x_1(t_0) = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)^T, \tag{11}$

$\vec x_2(t_0) = (0, 1, \ldots, 0)^T, \tag{12}$

$\vdots \tag{13}$

$\vec x_n(t_0) = (0, 0, \ldots, 1)^T; \tag{14}$

which may serve as initial conditions for $n$ linearly independent solutions of (1); then

$X^T(t, t_0)X(t, t_0) = I, \tag{15}$

that is, $X(t, t_0)$ is an orthogonal matrix for all $t \in I$.

Conversely, given that (15) binds, we find upon differentiation with respect to $t$ that

$\dot {X^T}(t, t_0) X(t, t_0) + X^T(t, t_0) \dot X(t, t_0) = 0, \tag{16}$

so that in light of (4) and (5),

$X^T(t, t_0)A^T(t)X(t, t_0) + X^T(t, t_0)A(t)X(t, t_0) = 0, \tag{17}$

or

$X^T(t, t_0)(A^T(t) + A(t))X(t, t_0) = 0; \tag{18}$

in accord with (9), both $X^T(t, t_0)$ and $X(t, t_0)$ are non-singular; thus

$A^T(t) + A(t) = 0, \tag{19}$

that is, (2) also holds.

There are a few special applications of these results which are worthy of mention; for example, if $\vec x(t)$ satisfies (1)-(2), then

$\dfrac{d}{dt}\langle \vec x(t), \vec x(t) \rangle = \langle \dot{\vec x}(t), \vec x(t) \rangle + \langle \vec x(t), \dot{\vec x}(t) \rangle = \langle A(t)\vec x(t), \vec x(t) \rangle + \langle \vec x(t), A(t) \vec x(t) \rangle$
$= \langle \vec x(t), A^T(t) \vec x(t) \rangle + \langle \vec x(t), A(t) \vec x(t) \rangle = \langle \vec x(t), A^T(t) \vec x(t) + A(t) \vec x(t) \rangle$
$= \langle \vec x(t), -A(t) \vec x(t) + A(t) \vec x(t) \rangle = \langle \vec x(t), 0 \rangle = 0, \tag{20}$

which shows that $\langle \vec x(t), \vec x(t) \rangle$ is constant.

In a like manner we may take things a step further and write

$\dfrac{d}{dt}\langle \vec x(t), \vec y(t) \rangle = \langle \dot{\vec x}(t), \vec y(t) \rangle + \langle \vec x(t), \dot{\vec y}(t) \rangle = \langle A(t)\vec x(t), \vec y(t) \rangle + \langle \vec x(t), A(t) \vec y(t) \rangle$
$= \langle \vec x(t), A^T(t) \vec y(t) \rangle + \langle \vec x(t), A(t) \vec y(t) \rangle = \langle \vec x(t), A^T(t) \vec y(t) + A(t) \vec y(t) \rangle$
$= \langle \vec x(t), -A(t) \vec y(t) + A(t) \vec y(t) \rangle = \langle \vec x(t), 0 \rangle = 0, \tag{21}$

which shows that inner products are preserved under the flow of (1)-(2).  Obviously (20) is a special case of (21) with $\vec y(t) = \vec x(t)$.

(20) and (21) also follow directly from (10) and (15), *viz* we have

$\vec x(t) = X(t, t_0) \vec x(t_0), \tag{22}$

$\vec y(t) = X(t, t_0) \vec y(t_0); \tag{23}$

thus,

$\langle \vec x(t), \vec y(t) \rangle = \langle X(t, t_0)\vec x(t_0), X(t, t_0) \vec y(t) \rangle = \langle \vec x(t_0), X^T(t, t_0) X(t, t_0) \vec y(t_0) \rangle$
$= \langle \vec x(t_0), I\vec y(t_0) \rangle = \langle \vec x(t_0), \vec y(t_0) \rangle, \tag{24}$

and of course taking $\vec y(t) = \vec x(t)$ yields

$\langle \vec x(t), \vec x(t) \rangle = \langle \vec x(t_0), \vec x(t_0) \rangle; \tag{25}$

no great surprise there.

We also note that, in accord with (6), $(X^T(t, t_0)X(t, t_0))'$ depends not only on $X(t, t_0)$ but also on $A_\Sigma(t)$, the symmetric part of $A(t)$:

$A_\Sigma(t) = \dfrac{A(t) + A^T(t)}{2}; \tag{26}$

the symmetric part of $A(t)$ vanishes when (2) or (7) bind; that is, when $A(t)$ is skew-symmetric.

Finally, in the event that (10) does not apply but that the columns of $X^T(t_0, t_0)$ remain linearly independent, we still have (9) with $X^T(t_0, t_0)X(t_0, t_0)$ positive definite symmetric, which may then be diagonalied by some orthogonal matrix $C$, yielding

$C^TX^T(t_0, t_0)X(t_0, t_0)C = \text{diag}(\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n), \tag{27}$

whence

$X^T(t_0, t_0)X(t_0, t_0) = C\text{diag}(\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n)C^T, \tag{28}$

with

$\mu_i > 0, \; 1 \le \mu_i \le n. \tag{29}$

We observe that (27) further implies

$\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^TX^T(t_0, t_0)$
$\cdot X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$= \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$\cdot \text{diag}(\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n)\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) = I, \tag{30}$

that is, $X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$ is orthogonal.  Furthermore, we have the equation

$\dfrac{d}{dt}(\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^TX^T(t, t_0) X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})) = (\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^TX^T(t, t_0) X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}))' = \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^T\dot {X^T}(t, t_0) X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) + \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^TX^T(t, t_0) \dot X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$= \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^TX^T(t, t_0)A^T(t) X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) + \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^TX^T(t, t_0)A(t)X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) = \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^TX^T(t, t_0)(A^T(t) + A(t))X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) = 0; \tag{31}$

combining (30) and (31) shows that

$\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^TX^T(t, t_0)$
$\cdot X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$= \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$\cdot \text{diag}(\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n)\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) = I, \tag{32}$

that is, $X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$ is orthogonal for all $t$.  These considerations indicate that the map

$X(t, t_0) \to X(t, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) \tag{33}$

transforms any fundamental solution matrix into an orthogonal one, having orthonormal rows and columns.  Applied to $X(t_0, t_0)$, (33) reads

$X(t_0, t_0) \to X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}), \tag{34}$

where $X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$ is orthogonal.  Since this matrix *is* orthogonal, we have

$X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$\cdot (X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}))^T = I, \tag{35}$

and

$(X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}))^T$
$\cdot X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) = I. \tag{36}$

We note that (35) may also be derived directly from (28) as follows:

$X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$\cdot (X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}))^T = X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})
\cdot \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^T X^T(t_0, t_0)$
$= X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1}, \mu_2^{-1}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1})
C^T X^T(t_0, t_0); \tag{37}$

inverting (28) and recalling that $(C^T)^{-1} = C$ and $C^{-1} = C^T$ since $C$ is orthogonal,

$X^{-1}(t_0, t_0)(X^T(t_0, t_0))^{-1} = C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1}, \mu_2^{-1}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1})C^T, \tag{38}$

and substituting this into (37) we see that

$X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$\cdot (X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}))^T= X(t_0, t_0)X^{-1}(t_0, t_0)(X^T(t_0, t_0))^{-1} X^T(t_0, t_0) = I. \tag{39}$

It is somewhat easier to see (36), for

$(X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}))^T$
$\cdot X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) $
$= \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})C^TX^T(t_0, t_0)$
$\cdot  X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) = I, \tag{40}$

and *via* (27) this becomes

$(X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}))^T$
$\cdot X(t_0, t_0)C\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$= \text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2})$
$\cdot \text{diag}(\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n)\text{diag}(\mu_1^{-1/2}, \mu_2^{-1/2}, \ldots, \mu_n^{-1/2}) = I. \tag{41}$

In closing, we pay respect to the geometrical interpretation of these results; in particular, (20)-(21) *und so weiter* show that systems such as (1)-(2) preserve inner products, and hence magnitudes of, and angles between, vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.  This view of things finds application in other situations, for example when considering the Frenet-Serret frames of curves in three-dimensional Euclidean space, and in higher dimensions as well.

***Nota Bene, Thursday 17 July 2020 2:59 PM PST:*** A few words to clarify certain aspects of the preceding dicussion.  We have claimed that (20), (21) follow directly from (10), (15) *via* (22) and (23).  We expand upon these remarks by observing that (10) yields the identities

$\vec x(t_0) = X(t_0, t_0) \vec x(t_0), \tag{42}$

$\vec y(t_0) = X(t_0, t_0) \vec y(t_0), \tag{43}$

and right multiplying (4) by $\vec x(t_0)$, $\vec y(t_0)$ we obtain

$\dot X(t, t_0)\vec x(t_0) = A(t) X(t, t_0)\vec x(t_0), \tag{44}$

$\dot X(t, t_0)\vec y(t_0) = A(t) X(t, t_0)\vec y(t_0); \tag{45}$

since $\vec x(t)$ and $\vec y(t)$ each satisfy (1), as (44) and (45) show $X(t, t_0)\vec x(t_0)$, $X(t, t_0)\vec y(t_0)$ do also, we see that $\vec x(t)$ and $X(t, t_0)\vec x(t_0)$ and $\vec y(t)$, $X(t, t_0) \vec y(t_0)$ satisfy the same equation(s) (1), (44)-(45) with the same initial conditions (42)-(43), hence by uniqueness of solutions to ordinary differential equations,

$\vec x(t) = X(t, t_0)x(t_0), \tag{46}$

and

$\vec y(t) = X(t, t_0)y(t_0), \tag{47}$

***End of Note.***

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach: Writing $x(t) =\Omega_t x(0)$ we have the following ode for $\Omega_t$:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \Omega_t = A_t \Omega_t, \ \ \ \Omega_t={\bf 1} .$$
Then
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \Omega_t^T \Omega_t = (A \Omega_t)^T \Omega_t + \Omega_t^T (A \Omega_t) =  - \Omega_t^T (A \Omega_t) +\Omega_t^T (A \Omega_t),$$
from which $$ \Omega_t^T \Omega_t = \Omega_0^T \Omega_0 = {\bf 1}, \ t\in {\Bbb R}.$$